# Making MySQL database available to use with my php code (on live website)

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysql-workbench, windows-server-2012

So over the last few days I've written some php code to add/update/remove stuff to a db & display it on another page. I used xampp (Apache webserver & MySQL database) when developing it so my db_config file had:

```
<?php
//DBCONFIG.php

class DBCONFIG {

    public static $db_conn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databasename;charset=utf8";
    public static $db_user = "username";
    public static $db_pass = "password";

}
```

Now the db I had (in phpMyAdmin) I recreated exactly (this time in MySQL Workbench). My question is what do I now put in my db_config file for the pages that are online? Do I need to do something extra with the database I created in MySQL Workbench? I also already created a new user in workbench that I wanted to use for this (Login Name: name, Authentication Type: Standard, Limit to Hosts Matching: localhost, Password: password) and gave it all the schema privileges for my database.

The pages are hosted on a VM Windows Server 2012 with IIS manager, MySQL Workbench is also running on that same VM.

Comment: So what you're trying to do is connect your live code to your local database?

Comment: @AndréFerraz Yes, is this possible or am I trying to do something that's not possible or a good idea?

Comment: @frequent_sleeper Of course you can do it, you just need to forward you database ip to a port in your router and make it available to to the internet. You will have to do some routing configuration. I can't put this into an answer because it would be too ambiguous.

Comment: @JmunozDev When I click Server Status in the Management panel of MySQL Workbench it says Host: ServerName, Socket: MySQL, Port:3306. But I tried putting ServerName in my db_config file but it didn't work (I also tried ServerName:3306 which also didn't work). Is the connection data I need somewhere else?

Comment: @AndréFerraz Oh, okay. I'm very new to this so I don't really know where to start. Do you maybe have some links or key words to google to get me started?

Comment: @JmunozDev Yes, I also tried that aswell as 127.0.0.1 & 127.0.0.1:3306

Comment: @JmunozDev "The domain page isn’t working

Domain is currently unable to handle this request."

Comment: @frequent_sleeper 127.0.0.1 is your local IP, you need to use your external IP but for it to work you need to forward you database to a port to work outside your network. What router do you have? Give me the model.